# vcpkg setup errors on command line

Tags: c++, python-2.7, windows-7, dlib, vcpkg

I am trying to compile dlib 19.4 using the [vcpkg tool](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg)

since I am having trouble compiling CMAKE and working with Boost.Python

to fix compiler issues for dlib.

Though I am having problems even running the basic steps

to get the vcpkg package to work:

(I also downloaded Visual Studio 2017 for this tool)

[image: cmd output part 1]
[image: cmd output part 2]
[image: cmd output part 3]

Answer (score 1):

Looking at executed command (*git init*), you initialized empty git repository for *vcpkg* - that is likely wrong. This *bootstrap.ps1* script fails internally when trying to fetch existing revisions. *vcpkg* doesn't want to reside in just any git repository, it wants "its" git repository. *vcpkg* uses git as a distribution platform and later to perform updates.

So instead, you should clone *vcpkg* repository to some directory, e.g.:

```
C:\test>git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git vcpkg_test
Cloning into 'vcpkg_test'...
...
Checking out files: 100% (876/876), done.

C:\test>cd vcpkg_test

C:\test\vcpkg_test>powershell -exec bypass scripts\bootstrap.ps1
```

https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/

Additionally I see errors regarding VS2017 C++ support. VS2017 is an IDE with multiple optionally supported languages (i.e. you could have only C# support installed). Please make sure you have "Desktop development with C++" workload installed - as *vcpkg* is for C++. You can update the installation at any time by running installer again (*Modify*).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio